# Optimize tableView scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My `tableView` scrolls with lags if extra populated. Up to 20 cells go well, but above - it starts lagging while scrolling. Please, suggest an implementation with a better scrolling result. Here is the way I did it:

I have defined a custom `UITableViewCell` class.

The cell has 4 labels and an `imageView` (each outlet is a synthesized property):
[image]

I have placed a `tableView` in my `viewController`, and populated it like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (MyCustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
    }
    [cell.label_descr setText:@"bla-bla-bla"];
    [cell.label_date setText:@"bla-bla-bla"];
    [cell.label_time setText:@"bla-bla-bla"];
    [cell.label_numeric setText:@"bla-bla-bla"];
    [cell.image_view setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"bla-bla-bla"]];

    return cell;
}
```

The amount of text in each cell, as you can see, is miserable, and the image used for the `UIImageView` is about 25x25 .png file.

My `tableView` is supposed to hold more than 300 cells (don't blame on me, I have a "customer from hell").

Please, suggest a way to make the `tableView` scroll smoother, without (much) lags. Or an alternative way to present those "damn-over-300-cells" to my "from hell" customer.

300 thanks in advance!

P.S.: sorry if duplicated, but the solutions found didn't help at all.

**EDIT:**

About the image used for the imageView:

I use 2 different images only:

1. a "checkmark" - transaction done
2. and a "pending" - transaction in process

Maybe I use to define 2 imageView outlets in my tableViewCell xib, and just selecting the needed imageView, instead of setting each time the required image?

**SOLUTION FOUND**, thanks to everybody, especially to iNoob and max_.

1. In tableViewCell's xib, I have set the "checkMark" as the default image of the imageView.
2. When defining the cell's values, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, only if needed, I say:

   `if_I_should_present_a_pending_image:`

   ```
      [cell setPending];
   ```

to replace the "checkMark" with a "pending" image (method defined in tableViewCell class):

```
- (void)setPending{
    self.image_view.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"pending_1.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"pending_2.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"pending_3.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"pending_4.png"],
                                    nil];
    self.image_view.animationDuration = 2.0;
    self.image_view.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [self.image_view startAnimating];
}
```

l

After that, the table scrolls like a charm. Thanks to everybody again. Cheers.

Comment: I faced this problem when i used `imageWithContentsOfFile`. In one application, i just copied all the images (around 210) in bundle and used `imageNamed` in other application i had to fetched images from URL so i tried with lazy loading and with help of SDWebImage library. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the answers, please, see also my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't iterate through all of the subviews: `cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];`
2. Load the images in the background using gcd, and store them in an NSDictionary for easy access:

Pseudo code:

```
If caches dict contains an object for the URL you want to load
    Retrieve that image from the dict
    Set it as the image
Else
    Load the image using dispatch_async()
    Add it to the dict
```

Comment: Thanks. This sounds to be very efficient when presenting different images for the imageView. +1, but take a look to my edit also.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/load-from-nib-or-construct-views-in.html) suggesting that creating the cells programatically instead of using a nib file could be up to 5-10% faster. I don't know if it's true or not, so take it with a grain of salt, but it may be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following one and try it out.

For the below code :

1) Take IBOutlet of your UITableViewCell in the your controller. for below code it is `myCustomTableViewCell`.

```
 MyCustomCell *customCell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];
 if(customCell == nil) {
     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
     customCell = myCustomTableViewCell;
  }
```

Hope it will work.